# Подключение а точнее import js файлов

Tags: javascript

На странице очень много js , существует ли способ как подключить их все , примерно как в css import ? создаётся отдельный файл - к примеру pull_script.js и в него импортируются все остальные или include ?

Comment: вообще перестаёт всё работать - я уже у google спрашивал - ответа не увидел и решил спросить здесь

Comment: Что перестаёт работать? Покажите код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует множество способов. На данный момент правильнее всего воспользоваться [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) или [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), это на самом деле просто  и примеров очень много на Github. Но в некоторые проекты ещё проще интегрировать [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) или написать асинхронный загрузчик.